# Absolute path for img and js excluding project folder name Visual Web Dev

Tags: path, visual-web-developer-2010

I've this little but annoying issue in my project in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I'm developing a website with .aspx files located in a large folder structure i.e. www.domain.com/group1/type1/somefile.aspx, the root folder contains a "styles" (for css), "images" and "js" (for javascripts) folder. I've read a lot about base tag, absolute and relative path today. Finally I realized "absolute path" is the best choice for me.

The main problem is that when I preview (locally) my site in browser the absolute links for image, css, and js are not working, I'm using `src="/js/gl.jquery.js"` which I believe is correct and will work online.

The source code of the page for the javascript says `http://localhost:61700/js/gl.jquery.js`, when I switch to relative path `script src="../../../js/gl.jquery.js"` and preview the website, it works fine, and the source code for the javascript path says `http://localhost:61700/ProjectName/js/gl.jquery.js` (Notice Visual Studio added the ProjectName in the path) So I'm taking my guess that when the project goes online (on a main domain) it will work correctly, but right now I need to keep developing locally without this issue. Is there a way to fix this in Visual Web Developer? maybe some tag for the web.config file that I can remove when goes online, or some website property?

I know a quick solution will be develop with the relative path, and modify the code when goes online to absolute path, but I'm looking for some cleaner method, as aditional information I didn't choose base tag because I read cause troubles with anchors links (href=xx.html#question3) and I need to use them at some big files. And avoid the relative path because it's possible that the company ask me to move some files in the future and I don't wanna be updating relative paths.

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! This is the solution I found Thanks to ScottGu's Blog.

**I quote the main thing:**
when opened a web-site  and run the project, VWD  launch and run the built-in web-server using a virtual app path that equals the project’s root directory name.  For example: if you have a project named “Foo”, it will launch and run in the built-in web-server as `http://localhost:1234/Foo/Default.aspx.`
One downside to this is that it makes it hard to fully qualify things like static CSS and image files within your site (for example: using root qualified paths like /images/myphoto.jpg or /css/mycss.css).  Note that you can use the “~” app path trick for **dynamic** resources – but **static** resources still end up being a pain (js, css, images files.) **(This was my issue)**

Here is the guy entire post: [Click Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx)

**Here is the main solution**:

1) Using the solution explorer within Visual Studio, select the web-site project node, (the one with the World icon)

2) There is a properties named "Virtual path" at the bottom.  Change the "virtual path" setting it to `/` to run as a root web-site.

And that's it, setting up the `/` I can manage my files easily.